# android checkbox show and hide

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a checkbox in linearlayout6 when i click on the checkbox i want to show linearlayout7,linearlayout8,linearlayout9. otherwise i want to hide these 3 linearlayout(7,8,9).

**checkbox**

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
/>
```

**XML**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string41" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string41"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string42" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAuthor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string42"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string43" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPublisher"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/string43"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string44" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtIsbn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/string44"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string45" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/string45" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout6">
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="@string/string46" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string47" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/string47" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string48" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/string48" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout9">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="@string/string49" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/string49" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/screen4layout10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:text="@string/save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:text="Delete" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: also you need to  default hide visibility of your layouts

Comment: I think this is very easy if you know or write android code then you defiantly know how to hide and show any views in android but if you don't know android development then pick this code from some where then it's difficult for you,

Comment: Did any answers solved your problem ? If yes, please mark it.Thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe Thank you. Its working.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I am new to android :D. I know how code works but was  not sure with linearlayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Add

```
android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
```

attribute to CheckBox in XML, then add the code below in .java file

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
// Is the view now checked?
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

// Check which checkbox was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkbox_meat:
        if (checked)
            showLayout789();
          //do things when checked
        else
            removeLayout789();
          // do things when unchecked
        break;

}
}
```

now find layouts using their id and set its visibility

```
private void showLayout789(){
View v9 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout9);
    v9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View v8 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout8);
    v8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
View v7 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout7);
    v7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

set invisible

```
 private void removeLayout789(){
View v9 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout9);
    v9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View v8 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout8);
    v8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View v7 = findViewById(R.id.screen4layout7);
    v7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the three `checkboxes` in your `xml` layout like what you did for the `checkbox1` and then specify id to them.

```
  CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxInLayout6);

     public void addListenerOnChk() // for checkbox
        {

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        checkBoxInLayout7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        checkBoxInLayout8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        checkBoxInLayout9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkBoxInLayout7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        checkBoxInLayout8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        checkBoxInLayout9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try these :**

```
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    ll7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    ll7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ll8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ll9.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    checkBoxInLayout7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    checkBoxInLayout8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    checkBoxInLayout9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxInLayout7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    checkBoxInLayout8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    checkBoxInLayout9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });
```

Try it easy one..

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                linearlayout7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearlayout8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearlayout9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                linearlayout7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearlayout8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearlayout9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Just simple code.
Happy to help